# How to create macro variables in python and recall them

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I have a python code and I am saving the results in a destination with specific file name, this file name will change every time and it is a recurring event.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
outfile=open('path.macrovariable.csv','w',newline='')
writer=csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Jobname","employement","company","descrption","location"])
writer.writerows([job_name])
writer.writerows([emplomnt_type])
writer.writerows([organisation])
writer.writerows([job_descrption])
writer.writerows([job_location])
```

In the outfile the file name here as "macrovariable" will change every time. I want to create a macrovariable at the top of the program which will be called later in the program in the place of "macrovariable" instead of hardcoding.

Thanks & regards,

Sanjay.